# Eclipse - Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0) not working for online syntax checking

Tags: mac, operating-systems, eclipse, javascript

I had Eclipse oxygen and tern as a Eclipse plug-in package to help with syntax checking of my Java script code. All of the sudden none of my javascript files did not showing any in-line syntax checking.  I am not sure what happened.

I am running on MacOS Mojave and I installed Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10.0) and I thought that this was the issue. I still do not see any type of syntax check in any of the javascript files.

The tern plugin, does not show up in the market place and when I use the drag and drop button, the plugin does not even get installed.

I even looked for other type of syntax checking plugin and found sonarLint but that is not even working on the Mac. IT gets installed but I do not see any of the syntax checking in the javascript file.

I am very dependent on the Javascript syntax to work on Eclipse. Anyone know what the issue with my installation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Tern plugin for eclipse is not supported for eclipse creater than 2018.09!

See https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tern-eclipse-ide in the Additional info.

Eclipse versions which are supported:

Neon (4.6), Mars (4.5), Luna (4.4), Kepler (4.3), Juno (4.2, 3.8), Previous to Juno (<=4.1), Oxygen (4.7), Photon (4.8), 2018-09 (4.9)